# How to push/merge code from a feature branch into another integration branch in git?

Tags: git, merge, branch, gitlab, git-branch

I have the following setup strategy for releasing multiple features to a common uat environment (integration). As soon as I am done with one feature, I eventually want to merge that feature, and only the contents of that, feature into the release branch, and then finally into the master branch.

```
 origin/master
      |__origin/release
      |__origin/integration
      |__origin/featureOne
      |__origin/featureTwo
```

My question is how do I merge the contents of a local branch **featureOne** into the remote branch **origin/integration**?

This is what I am currently doing:

1. git clone `http://mygitServer/myGroupName/myApp.git`
2. `git checkout featureOne`
3. Perform some code changes
4. `git add fileName`
5. `git commit --message 'Comment for my code change'`
6. `git push`

The last git command, push, pushes the new code in my local branch from the local repository to our gitlab remote server. specifically into **origin/featureOne**

1. What is the git command to merge my local/featureOne to the origin/integration branch?
2. Or would it make more sense to merge origin/featureOne into origin/integration? What would be the git command be for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this command sequence:

```
git checkout integration
git merge featureOne
git commit
git push
```

Comment: When I do a git push it tells me everything is up-to-date but I checked my remote and things are not there. Do I have to do a commit first? If so how do I commit everything in one command without specifying each file one by one? Thanks

Comment: I had to perform a git commit between the git merge and the git push. Thanks though it worked.